# Staggered Grid Layout Manager that works in both orientations

Tags: android, android-layout, staggeredgridlayout, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to create a staggered grid layout that takes items with varying width ***and*** height. The layout dynamically moves items around so they don't overlap.

**What I have tried:**

I looked into using the default `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, but it appears to only work in one orientation (i.e. Vertical *or* Horizontal). Furthermore, every library or tutorial I've come across also only deals with items containing either a dynamic height or dynamic width, but not both.

Is there a way to make the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` dynamically span both vertically and horizontally? Or will I have to create my own custom layout manager? If the latter, could someone point me in the right direction to learn about how one would create such a layout manager?

Comment: Hello @Matthew, I am also facing same problem did you solved it? if yes can you please tell me how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, `GridLayoutManager`can be used with `spanSizeLookup`. Using `spanSizeLookup`, we can specify the column span.

```
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
@Override
public int getSpanSize(int position) {
 item[position].columnSpan
}
}
```

While creating the GridLayoutManager , specify the max no of columns like this

```
layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, MAX_NUM_COL)
```

The row span can be applied by calculating the height using the spanning factor and height of the parent

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However won't this only manipulate either the width or the height (depending on the orientation of the LayoutManager)? I need to manipulate *both* independently

Comment: using spanSizeLookup, only columnSpan can be manipulated. In order to apply row span, compute the height in recycler view adapter using parent as (recycler view's total height) and current row span info for every item 

`rowHeight = (recyclerView.height * rowSpan)/MAX_ROW`